# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^k x^n=0$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, and $0<x<1$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I was studying uniform convergence of sequences of functions, where I encountered the following problem:

Establish that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n^k x^n=0$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, and $0<x<1$. I think putting $x=\frac{1}{(1+y)^{k+1}}$, and using Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+y)^{(k+1)n}\geq (1+ny)^{k+1}\geq n^{k+1}y^{k+1}$ will provide us
$n^kx^n\leq \frac{1}{y^{k+1}}\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow 0$. Any other method of doing so?

Comment: I would use $x^n = \mathrm{e}^{n\ln x}$ where for $0<x<1$ we have $\ln x < 0$ so we have $x^n = \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{n\alpha}}$ then you can compare $$\frac{n^k}{\mathrm{e}^{n\alpha}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting $x = \frac{1}{y}$ with $y > 1$, you can use L'Hopital's rule taking k-times derivatives.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the series $\sum n^k x^n$.

The ratio test says that this series converges if $0 < |x| < 1$ and so its terms must converge to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha=\frac2{1+x}\gt1$. Then $\alpha x=\frac{2x}{1+x}\lt1$.

Since $\left(1+\frac1t\right)^k$ is a decreasing function of $t$, if
$$
n_0\ge\frac{(\alpha x)^{1/k}}{1-(\alpha x)^{1/k}}
$$
then if $n\ge n_0$,
$$
\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^kx\le\frac1\alpha
$$
Therefore, for $n\ge n_0$,
$$
\begin{align}
n^kx^n
&\le\overbrace{n_0^kx^{n_0}\vphantom{\frac1{\alpha^n}}}^{\text{fixed}}\overbrace{\frac1{\alpha^{n-n_0}}}^{\text{vanishes}}\\[6pt]
&=n_0^kx^{n_0}\left(\frac{1+x}2\right)^{n-n_0}
\end{align}
$$